# Jquery modal imagen with zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a modal with image content and also, to zoom the image. I have 2 qualities of photos one is horrible and another is excellent. The idea is to see a preview of the bad image, but when clicking to see a good image and to zoom. I have tried to implement different modal plugins and zoom but none works correctly because as I post pictures. The'm getting from my database and go around with for all my records. As explained above I have two qualities of images, I do it because it is a selling software images. My idea is that only the administrator can see the image of good quality. That's why I want to do the lifting of the images by a modal and zoom to them.

For zoom? Because the images contain runners and each runners has a number. When the user wants to buy your images just simply to look up your race number and I give all pictures that contain it, but when the load manager pictures can deliver a number and is saved in the database connected to that image specific.

I was trying with this plugin that I seemed very good and worked, but not within a modal.

[zoom img](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/magnifying-glass-for-images)

and this modal Bootstrap that I found comfortable

[modal](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/easy-image-gallery-in-a-modal)

I do not need code, just need to know if there is any plugin to do more or less what I need, to take actions to the buttons and make a more or less clean a better quality image zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some zoom plugins:
[enter link description here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-zoom-effect/)

Hope it helps;)

Comment: If, in my project if added jquery, as I said before, zoom plugins if all work well, but within the modal no.